# How to trace the reason of org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException on Zeppelin/EMR

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin, apache-spark-ml

I am struggling in getting the my code running on Zeppelin on EMR (emr-5.10.0, Zeppelin 0.7.3, Spark 2.2.0).

The code is straight forward, fitting a `CrossValidator` with`RandomForestClassifier` on a training DataFrame of 400K samples (~40K positives and 360K negatives).

When I run a simple training (say 100 trees with 15 max depth) everything goes OK, but when I run a heavier test with more values in the `ParamGridBuilder` I get a `org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException` and I do not know how to trace the reason of that error.

I am using a cluster of three c3.8xlarge machines with the following settings of Spark interpreter on Zeppelin:

```
spark.executor.memory = 15g
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead = 2048
spark.executor.cores = 10
```

I played with `spark.memory.fraction` without success, I also tried to change the number of executors by playing with the three settings above, without success.

I have a feeling that it is rather a zeppelin problem but I am not able to trace the reason of the exception. I looked into the logs without finding any exception other than the `TTransportException`, which is not helpful by itself.

Any help or hint in how to trace the reaction of the exception is highly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer, VectorAssembler}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

val genreIndexer = new StringIndexer()
                        .setInputCol("genre")
                        .setOutputCol("genreIndex")
                        .setHandleInvalid("skip")

val genreEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
                        .setInputCol(genreIndexer.getOutputCol)
                        .setOutputCol("genreVec")

val featuresAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
                            .setInputCols(Array("hourOfDay", "dayOfWeek_number", "dayOfMonth", "genreVec"))
                            .setOutputCol("features")

val classifier = new RandomForestClassifier()
                    .setLabelCol("label")
                    .setFeaturesCol("features")

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
                   .addGrid(classifier.numTrees, Array(200, 400))
                   .addGrid(classifier.maxDepth, Array(10, 20))
                   .build()

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(genreIndexer, genreEncoder, featuresAssembler, classifier))

val cv = new CrossValidator()
              .setEstimator(pipeline)
              .setEvaluator(new BinaryClassificationEvaluator)
              .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
              .setNumFolds(3)

val cvModel = cv.fit(train_df)
```

Here is the exception as I see it in the logs and on Zeppelin:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:266)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:250)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:373)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:97)
at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:406)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:329)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Zeppelin is very sensistive to the dependencies you load, do you have added dependencies here ?

Comment: No dependencies are added. The cluster has only Spark and Zeppelin, no Hadoop nor Give etc.

Comment: I have installed Python modules in a bootstrap action, an set some Spark default parameters when creating the cluster, but I override these parameters from Zeppelin interpreter. Shall I try a raw cluster, or probably an older version?

Comment: Can you check Zeppelin logs ? Unfortunately, Zeppelin isn’t a stable tool. Tracing errors like this tend to be a nightmare.

Comment: Where can I find Zeppelin logs?

Comment: I’m sorry I don’t recall the exact location now. I’m not on a computer now.

Comment: I’m sick in bed.

Comment: Don't worry Elia, get well soon :)

Comment: @eliasah it worked after removing the Bootstrap action that was installing many python module.

Comment: This means that there is a python module that is breaking Zeppelin. You’ll need to isolate it :-/